# does not contain a definition defination

Tags: c#

After i declare this,  this is the error i get

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<String> LabelTextList = new List<String>();
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
        LabelTextList.add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
 }
```

Error   1   'MasterPage_Profile' does not contain a definition for 'LabelTextList' and no extension method 'LabelTextList' accepting a first argument of type 'MasterPage_Profile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[UPDATE] Now it says :

'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: For a start List<String> LabelTextList = new List<String>(); should be List<String> labelTextList = new List<String>(); And this.LabelTextList.add(dr[0].ToString()); should be labelTextList.add(dr[0].ToString());

Comment: unless you've declared a field called LabelTextList then you're not going to get to it using the this keyword. You've scoped it at method level so this isn't required and isn't applicable

Comment: @PaulZahra I have changed it . The name 'labelTextList' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: It looks like you have the casing of the variable name wrong.  The case must match exactly.  `LabelTextList` is different than `labelTextList`

Answer (score 4):

Remove `this` - `LabelTextList` is a local variable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<String> LabelTextList = new List<String>();
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            LabelTextList.add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
 }
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. It is clear that the OP has not got the basics of C# OOP. First by using "this" to reference a local variable. In addition, not following basic c# coding syntax guidelines (e.g. LabelTextList  should be labelTextList).

Answer (score 2):

To fix this change it to the following

```
LabelTextList.Add(dr[0].ToString());
```

The `LabelTextList` value is a local variable definition.  When you prefix an expression with `this.` it tells the compiler to look for members of the value, not locals.

Here is a counter example with a field named `LabelTextList` that works with `this.`

```
List<String> LabelTextList = new List<String>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      this.LabelTextList.Add(dr[0].ToString());
   }
}
```

Also if you keep the value as a local the standard naming pattern would be `labelTextList` instead of `LabelTextList`.  This isn't required by the language but is the preferred style.

Comment: i have changed. but the error still come out. It still having the same one

Comment: @user3021598 the code in mine or Jakub's sample should work just fine.  It should at least be removing the initial error you got.  Are you getting a new one now?

Comment: Yes, there a new error .  The name 'labelTextList' does not exist in the current context.